# How to automatically prompt the user for an action after app is downloaded from google play?

Tags: android, google-play

I am new to `android`. I want to - whether i can configure my app so that when it is installed on a device, it should automatically starts in the similar way a app is downloaded from the google play( i.e., after installation a new screen will appear with two buttons "open" and "Done" prompting the user to do some kind of action before the app launch). I like to know whether this functionality is in built in `android` os or are the apps in `google play` are coded(something in `manifest`) in such a   way that after installation it should prompt the user to do action? I googled about it, i can't find any satisfactory explanation. Most of the explanation goes on behalf of security reasons. Any help or guidance in this issue is highly appreciable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont need to configure in your `manifest` and anyways you cant do that. `Android` will take care of that. If you copy some sample `apk` file into Android phone( either it is `phone memory/SD card`) and click that, a window will be opened asks for install. After installation , another window will be displayed with two options: `OPEN, DONE`. Same thing will be happened if you download the app from `Google Play`.

Comment: so if i put an app in google play or in any other android store as in the normal way, after downloading will it automatically  ask the user to install and after installation will it automatically show the screen with "OPEN" and "Done" Button to user?

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately you cannot do that for security reasons. User needs to launch app by hand. There were some tricks for older versions of android, but these are fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that.

Why don't you have a configuration screen on the first time the app is opened by the user? It's the common approach.

Store a boolean on SharedPreferences like "isFirstRun" to know if you should show the configuration screen or not.